# $.post validate form field and blck submit is there is error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to validate form field on submit and if ajax returns message to block the form submit. Here is the js code I have:

```
$('form.p_form').submit(function (){
var description = $.trim($('#f9').val());
var aa = $.post("checkdescription.php",{
     description: description
 },
 function(data, status){
    if(data !== ''){
    return data;
    }
 });

 if(aa){
 alert(aa);
 return false;
 }
});
```

but the code above always returns [object XMLHttpRequest] - How to read the mesage returned?

basicaly in checkdescription.php I have php code that validates the field and if there is error it puts in:

```
$return ='error message'; 

//file ends with:

echo json_encode($return);
```

how can I read the exact message received from response?

thank you in advance !

I also tried this:

```
    $('form.p_form').submit(function (){
var description = $.trim($('#f9').val());
var aa = $.post("checkdescription.php",{
     description: description
 },
 function(data, status){
    if(data !== ''){
    return false;
    }
 });
```

but it doesnt prevent form submit..

Comment: Why not use `e.preventDefault()` and not `return false`?

Comment: Have you tried printing the XMLHttpRequest to the console? If you inspect it, you might be able to find where your missing parameter is hiding in the object

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Please see edited question at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

It's required that you also set PHP header to application/json because, this output can be easily read by JQuery's ajax or $.post function, more a structured JSON output is also needed, here's how you should do it...

### for PHP

```
<?php
$output = array('status'=>'true','message'=>'your error message');
//Setting up the output MIME type
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
//Providing Structured Output
echo json_encode($output);
```

this will be easily read by ajax...

### For Javascript

```
$('form.p_form').submit(function (){
var description = $.trim($('#f9').val());
var aa = $.post("checkdescription.php",{
description: description
},
 function(data, status){
   return data['status'];
   }
});
```